# Hide octave-workspace file from home directory

Tags: configuration, config, octave, configuration-files

I would like to change the file `octave-workspace` from my home directory, simply renaming it to `.octave_workspace`. How can I manage to make octave recognize a workspace file (or create a new one) with this new name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the purpose of the `octave_core_file_name()` function.

Add the following to your `.octaverc` file:

```
octave_core_file_name (".octave-workspace")
```

Comment: Didn't work. `.octaverc` wasn't on my home directory. I created one, added the line you suggested and nothing..

Comment: @brk0_0, you need to restart the interpreter every time you set your `.octaverc`.

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work. It's like `.octaverc` didn't exist.

Comment: Please print something in your `.octaverc` like `display ("HEY!")`.

Answer (score 1):

**OSX Solution:**

You can use chflags

To hide a file from Finder:

```
chflags hidden /Path/To/File
```

To unhide:

```
chflags nohidden /Path/To/File
```

**Linux Solution:**

From what I'm reading here, you can create a "hidden" files file, which contains a list of files to hide.  I haven't read it fully, nor did I test it, as I don't use Linux.

http://www.fandigital.com/2012/09/better-way-to-hide-file-folder-in.html