# octave: disable octave-workspace crash file

Tags: configuration, octave

How can I disable Octave from creating an octave-workspace file within the working directory when it crashes?

I don't see any option to disable it in [octave_core_file_options()](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/octave_core_file_options.html). Is this possible? Maybe through a hack by automatically removing the file at termination? (the problem is .octaverc runs at start)

Related (but not duplicate): [Hide octave-workspace file from home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635187/hide-octave-workspace-file-from-home-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `crash_dumps_octave_core`:

> Query or set the internal variable that controls whether Octave tries to save all current variables to the file 'octave-workspace' if it crashes or receives a hangup, terminate or similar signal.

Just for completeness, the reason why this family of functions (`octave_core_file_limit`, `octave_core_file_name`, and `octave_core_file_options`) have "octave_core" on the name instead of "octave_workspace", is that on older releases the default name of the file was "octave-workspace".

How could you have found this yourself?

1. from your question, you already knew about `octave_core_file_options`. If you see the bottom of that function help text, you will find:

   > See also: crash_dumps_octave_core, octave_core_file_name, octave_core_file_limit.
2. Take a look at the manual section about this function by calling `doc octave_core`
3. you can use the `lookfor` command to search functions:

   ```
   octave> lookfor octave_core
   crash_dumps_octave_core Query or set the internal variable that controls whethe
                       r Octave  tries to save all current variables to the file '
                       'octave-workspace'  if it crashes or receives a hangup, ter
                       rminate or similar signal.
   octave_core_file_limit Query or set the internal variable that specifies the ma
                       ximum  amount of memory (in kilobytes) of the top-level wor
                       rkspace that  Octave will attempt to save when writing data
                       a to the crash dump  file (the name of the file is specifie
                       ed by OCTAVE_CORE_FILE_NAME).
   octave_core_file_name Query or set the internal variable that specifies the nam
                       e of the  file used for saving data from the top-level work
                       kspace if Octave  aborts.
   octave_core_file_options Query or set the internal variable that specifies the 
                       options used  for saving the workspace data if Octave abort
                       ts.
   sighup_dumps_octave_core Query or set the internal variable that controls wheth
                       er Octave  tries to save all current variables to the file
                       'octave-workspace'  if it receives a hangup signal.
   sigterm_dumps_octave_core Query or set the internal variable that controls whet
                       her Octave  tries to save all current variables to the file
                       e 'octave-workspace'  if it receives a terminate signal.
   ```

Comment: Oh thanks. I am a long time Octave user and I was under the impression that the `octave-workspace` was created always, not just when you have errors. I guess I never make one script without some error hehe. The filename is very unintuitive. Thanks again!

Comment: @RicardoCruz it's not every time you get an error, it's when it crashes. If you always get one, you must be doing something wrong. What are you doing to exit Octave?

Comment: ah!! I just close the terminal window while it is still running oh... that's why creates the core file... I feel embarrassed :P

Comment: @RicardoCruz there is an `exit()` function to actually exit Octave. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> keyboard shortcut (sends EOF signal, not sure if it works in non-Linux)

Comment: Yes, I know, it's just out of laziness. :) By the way, I have rephrased the question slightly to reflect the fact the file only gets created on crashes.