# No .octaverc file in home directory

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I cannot find the startup file .octaverc in my home directory. It does not show up using `ls -a`. I would like to run certain commands when Octave starts up using the .octaverc file.

[This documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Startup-Files.html) makes it seem like the .octaverc file should already be located there. Do I need to make it myself, or did I install Octave incorrectly?

I know I could run the commands in the global configuration .octaverc file, but I don't want the changes to be global.

When I use Octave I use it through the Octave GUI, not through the command line. I am not sure if that affects anything.

I searched for an answer to this, and I didn't find much. User "prcastro" had the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636289/5096422) - he did not have a .octaverc file in his home directory.

I am running Octave 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed it using the package manager: `sudo apt-get install octave`.

Comment: you have to create it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I ran 'savepath' at some point which made the file for me.